# Trouble getting polylines to render with angular-cesium

Tags: angular, cesiumjs

I am trying out angular-cesium and cannot get polylines rendering in my application.

My component html is as follows:

```
<ac-map>
  <ac-layer acFor="let path of paths$" [context]="this">
    <ac-polyline-desc props="{
        position: path.positions,
        width: path.width,
        material: path.material
    }">
    </ac-polyline-desc>
  </ac-layer>
</ac-map>
```

And the ts source:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AcNotification, ActionType } from 'angular-cesium';
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  paths$: Observable<AcNotification>;

  ngOnInit() {
    const yellowMaterial = new Cesium.Material({
      fabric: {
        type: 'Color',
        uniforms: {
          color: new Cesium.Color(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        }
      }
    });

    this.paths$ = from([
      {
        id: '1',
        width: 2,
        positions: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray(
          [
            -3.131172, 51.478424,
            18.492839, 51.649888
          ]),
        material: yellowMaterial
      }
    ]).pipe(
      map(path => ({
        id: path.id,
        actionType: ActionType.ADD_UPDATE,
        entity: path
      }))
    );

  }
}
```

This is based on the 'planes' basic [example](https://github.com/articodeltd/angular-cesium#basic-example), which I can get to work just fine. So I must be doing something subtly wrong when trying to use the polyline variation with multiple points, or something else even more stupid?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't test your code atm code but in my app I am doing something like this =>

```
`<ac-layer acFor="let drone of acDrones$" [context]="this"></ac-layer>`

public acEntity$: Observable<AcNotification>;
private acEntityEmitter: Subject<AcNotification> = new Subject<AcNotification>();

constructor() {
    this.acEntity$ = this.acEntityEmitter.asObservable();
}

addEntity() {
    this.acEntityEmitter.next({
      id: uuid(),
      actionType: ActionType.ADD_UPDATE,
      entity: new AcEntity({
        position,
        orientation
      })
    });
}
```

Maybe it can help you. If not please comment, and I will remember to try it